# class diagram clarification for hospital management

Tags: java, uml

I have need to verify whether I have correctly identify the relationship among those classes. 
For example Suppose I have below entities,

```
Doctor 1---------m Diagnosis m----------m Prescriptions m ----------1 Patient
  1                                                                      m
  -                                                                      -
  -                                                                      -
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So its basically diagnosis is a reference table where a admin doctor entered all the diagnosis details. For example,

```
Diag_ID, Category, Name,       Desc
1        Skin      Red Skin    Red spots in skin
```

So my business flow is Doctor going to create a prescription for a patient. So he will be giving a patient id (patient registration also happen but i didn't display those entity).
Then from Doctor.createPrescription(patientId) he will refer to the Diagnosis table and create prescription with relevant details. Suppose the prescription class constructor takes new Prescription(diagnonsisId,doctorId,patientID).

Is it a correct way to identify the relationship among them. 
**Is it correct to link doctor and diagnosis class when creating the prescription.** Doctor can also create a new diagnosis type if its not exsits.

So one doctor can diagnose a patient with more than one symptoms. For example one with skin and another one with Chest. so in that case 1 doctor can have many diagnosis. But all those should be done by one doctor. So for each diagnonsis doctor can issue seperate prescriptions or a one prescription can issue for all diagnoses. So its a many to many relationship. Finally those prescriptions should be belong to a one patient. Can not share between patients. I guess my model is right know?

What if multiple doctors can diagnose a patient. How to extend this to support that requirement?

Any suggestions and if this model wrong from start. please suggest a new model

Comment: Though many patients will require patience while waiting for the doctor, they probably don't like being called this. Consider changing "Patience" to "Patient".

Comment: I know. I was just joking a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

To consider:

- The patient is the one with the diagnosis list, and so the diagnosis list should be held by the Patient class
- A Doctor will be allowed to modify this list and create Prescriptions for a given Diagnosis.
- Multiple Doctors can modify a Patient's Diagnosis list
- but when one Doctor is modifying this list, he should hold a lock on this list and not release it until he is done.
- Other doctors can view the list when the lock is active, but they should not be able to modify it until the lock is released.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it a correct way to identify the relationship among them**

It is one way, and it seems accurate enough.

**Is it correct to link doctor and diagnosis class when creating the prescription**

Think about immutablility; if a diagnosis can't change over time (this is probably true), then it seems easiest to require all three in the constructor, and then make the class immutable.

**What if multiple doctors can diagnose a patient. How to extend this to support that requirement?**

```
Doctor m---------m Diagnosis
   m
```